# Flask + uwsgi + nginx: TypeError: ... takes no arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I installed uwsgi with nginx on my ubuntu 12.04 homerserver and try to test a simple Flask-App:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def application():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

with `python app.py` it works. 
But not with `uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --file /srv/www/test/app.py --callable application --catch-exceptions`

I just get a this error `TypeError: application() takes no arguments (2 given)` and don't know why. Where this two arguments come from?

Here is my uwsgi.conf:

```
  1 description "uWSGI Emperor"
  2 start on runlevel [2345]
  3 stop on runlevel [06]
  4 respawn
  5
  6 exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
```

and my nginx.conf

```
server {
 94      listen 8000;
 95      server_name localhost;
 96      root /srv/www/test;
 97
 98      location /static/ {
 99      alias /srv/www/test/static/;
100      expires 30d;
101      access_log off;
102      }
103
104      location / {
105      include uwsgi_params;
106      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
107  }
108 }
```

i try it before with an .ini-file in apps-enabled but i get this way errors too.

I hope that someone can help me. :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"application" is a flask callable (defined by you) not a WSGI callable (like you configured in uWSGI). Your WSGI callable is "app" (the main entry point). Just change --callable application to --callable app