# nginx & uWsgi TypeError: main() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I've been following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-uwsgi-web-server-with-nginx) tutorial for setting up a Pyramid wsgi application via uWsgi. I am currently up to "Option #2: Using .ini files for configurations".

When I run the following:

```
uwsgi --ini example_config.ini
```

It all starts up nicely and lists 5 uwsgi processes etc etc. When I load the page I get a "502 bad gateway" in my browser and in the terminal with the uwsgi processes I get the following:

```
TypeError: main() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I've googled as much as I can and I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847477/flask-uwsgi-nginx-typeerror-takes-no-arguments-2-given) but I can't understand how to apply that to my situation.

This is the first time I've used uwsgi so I'm guessing it's something very simple I'm missing. The Pyramid app itself is the exact one that is generated with:

```
pcreate -s alchemy venustate
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [r/python](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/22jl1h/nginx_uwsgi_typeerror_main_takes_1_positional/) for finding the solution to this one.

Comment: Links are not answers. Please tell us what the solution was.